# Simple PowerShell question - How to convert object into arraylist

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, arraylist, grouping

I have a variable that contains the following:

```
Site                      IP

walmart                   10.20.30.40
walmart                   10.20.30.41
walmart                   10.20.30.42
target                    10.20.30.50
target                    10.20.30.51
hm                        10.20.30.60
```

This is an object created using `New-Object psobject -Property @{ site = <code> ; IP = <code> }`. So if I call `$obj.site`, it does list only the sites and same goes with IP.

I want to convert this is into an arraylist *grouped* by the sites.

For instance, result output should look like this:

```
walmart     :  {10.20.30.40, 10.20.30.41, 10.20.30.42}
target      :  {10.20.30.50, 10.20.30.51}
hm          :  {10.20.30.60}
```

I want to be able to call this from my script like for reasons like adding or subtracting IPs on any site. For instance:

```
$myArray.target
```

Which should list the IPs like:

```
10.20.30.50
10.20.30.51
```

Instead of the same format - `{10.20.30.50, 10.20.30.51}`

Then I would add more IPs to these object using the Add method.

```
($myArray.walmart).Add("10.20.30.44")
```

The closest I've been able to get is the following (and its output):

```
$obj | Group-Object -Property Site | Select-Object Name,Group

Name            Group

walmart         {@{Site=walmart; IP=10.20.30.40}, @{Site=walmart; IP=10.20.30.41}, @{Site=walmart; IP=10.20.30.42}
target          {@{Site=target; IP=10.20.30.50}, @{Site=target; IP=10.20.30.51}
hm              {@{Site=hm; IP=10.20.30.60}
```

With that output, I can't call on particular site like `$myArray.walmart`.

I'm pretty new to powershell, what am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you looked at using a hashtable? that lets you have a unique key [the site] and a value that can be a singleton, OR an array. it makes looking up site info quite quick ... `$LookupTable['SiteName']` will give you all the IPs. then `$LookupTable['SiteName'][0]` would give you the 1st item in the array of items in the value of that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
$Array=@(
[pscustomobject]@{Site='walmart'; ID='10.20.30.40'}
[pscustomobject]@{Site='walmart'; ID='10.20.30.41'}
[pscustomobject]@{Site='walmart'; ID='10.20.30.42'}
[pscustomobject]@{Site='target'; ID='10.20.30.50'}
[pscustomobject]@{Site='target'; ID='10.20.30.51'}
[pscustomobject]@{Site='hm'; ID='10.20.30.60'}
)

$Object=New-Object PSObject

$Array | group Site | %{

#create an new list with all id for the curretn group
$CurrentList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$_.group.ID | %{$CurrentList.Add($_)}

#Add property and list to the final object
Add-Member Noteproperty -Name $_.Name -value $CurrentList -InputObject $Object
}

#add element to a site
$Object.hm.Add("NewID")
```

Comment: Thank you @Esperento57! That helped a lot!